# Parent- Child UIViewControllers IOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, parse-platform

So, I am looking at the code from Parse Anypic tutorial [here](https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic)
 and my question is this :

There are these 2 view controllers :

```
@interface PAPHomeViewController : PAPPhotoTimelineViewController


@end

and this one :

@interface PAPPhotoTimelineViewController : PFQueryTableViewController <PAPPhotoHeaderViewDelegate>

- (PAPPhotoHeaderView *)dequeueReusableSectionHeaderView;

@end
```

I have a segue let's say that opens the homeViewController.

What is the relationship between these two? Both of the viewcontrollers have implemented the viewDidLoad function - and they are both called.  In what order are they called? Is any of them having priority over the other? I do not understand the idea of a viewcontroller that extends another viewcontroller.

Can I have my HomeViewController extends the UIViewController and the PhotoTimeline to be initiated inside the HomeViewController, given a specific frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably `PAPHomeViewController` is the one you are actually instantiating. If that's the case, then its `viewDidLoad` gets called, if it has one. If `PAPHomeViewController` calls `[super viewDidLoad]` within its viewDidLoad method then `PAPPhotoTimelineViewController` will be called at that point. In turn, if `PAPPhotoTimelineViewController` calls `[super viewDidLoad]` then `PFQueryTableViewController`s viewDidLoad will be called.

This process will continue all the way up to `UIViewController`s viewDidLoad method.

You asked

> What is the relationship between these two?

I strongly suggest you stop programming for a bit and read up on basic programming principles. Especially read anything you can find on "implementation inheritance".